# Why don't we have an intrinsic representation of complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question

In many ways that I probably don't have to list here the complex numbers $\mathbb C$ arise very naturally, many times they seem to be the more natural set of numbers to work with than real numbers $\mathbb R$.

However whenever we *do* work with them, it seems that we always use the crutch of representing them as a pair of real numbers, here just a list of a few examples:

$$a+ib \qquad re^{i\varphi} \qquad \begin{bmatrix} u & -v \\ v & u \end{bmatrix} \qquad r+sx + (1+x^2)\mathbb R[x]$$

However natural they are, it seems we don't really have an "intrinsic" representation of the complex numbers that we can work with - at least not that I am aware of. So this leads me to the following questions:

Why is that the case? Or is there anything closer to an *intrinsic* representation than anything similar to the above examples, i.e. that does not use just a pair of real numbers?

Comment: By intrinsic do you mean one dimensional?

Comment: @R.Burton That could be an interpretation yes, but also anything else that doensn't rely on actually representing them as pair of reals.

Comment: @eyeballfrog That is just a variable.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 You can indeed ask that for every other step in the chain of the construction that leads to complex numbers, but here I'm particularly interested in this case of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @flawr what MathematicsStudent1122 says is that **everything** is built on top of something else. Until you reach the notion of set which has sort of blurry, axiomatic definition. So what kind of "intrinsic representation" are you talking about? What does it even mean?

Comment: The complex number are "intrinsically" a vector space of dimension two over the real numbers.  Using a pair of real numbers to represent a complex number **is** pretty "intrinsic"!

Comment: $\mathbb C$ does have one very different property from $\mathbb R$ and its subsets: it's not linearly ordered. Perhaps that's part of the issue?

Comment: Might [quater-imaginary base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quater-imaginary_base) be the sort of representation you are looking for?

Comment: @Allawonder I obviously cannot define it, hence the [tag:soft-question] tag, but the comments form above should get you an idea.

Comment: @fleablood Complex numbers are one dimensional as a vector space over themselves. And they have a lot more dimensions over other fields.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks for the constructive input, that is an interesting thought and certainly contributes to this. Compared to the construction of the intermediate steps (natural, integers, rationals, reals) in the complex numbers this is not the case anymore for the first itme.

Comment: @freakish as I said, that is not so clear (hence the [tag:soft-question]-tag) but had hoped my examples give some intuition.

Comment: @pregunton That is a really interesting idea, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's start with the fact that in mathematic everything is built on top of something else. Complex numbers are built on top of reals. Reals on top of rationals, rationals on top of integers, integers on top of naturals, naturals on top of sets. Wherever you start, as long as you go deep enough you will eventually reach sets, which are not really defined, they just are. They are supposed to obey some axioms, yes, but they are not constructed from anything.

So I guess you can say that sets have an intrinsic representation. But nothing else in maths. Well at least in [ZF set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (we do have to assume something, right?).

Now you've said that complex numbers are defined in terms of reals and that is not an intrinsic representation. But do reals have an intrinsic representation? Reals are constructed from rationals as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences (there are other equivalent constructions, it doesn't matter). So each of these symbols $1, 7, -4, \frac{1}{3}, \sqrt{2}, \pi$ **is just a convention**. It is a label, it is not a real number. The real real number is an equivalence class of some Cauchy sequence. And those labels are far from perfect, there are not enough words (in a natural language, which I assume is at most countable) to construct every possible real number. We are just so used to these few common labels being used every day that they seem so natural to us. But let me remind you that few hundreds years ago that wasn't the case. For example [Diophantus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantus) considered negative numbers as "useless, meaningless, and even absurd".

Anyway, in a similar manner you can invent some arbitrary convention, some "labels", that will represent complex numbers in a new way. But this feels like cheating, because the essence stays the same: complex numbers are pairs of reals, you can't avoid that. Just like you can't avoid the fact that rationals are inside reals, you can only hide that.

That being said, you can argue that there is [the axiomatic approach to reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Axiomatic_approach). But as I've mentioned earlier, axioms do not define anything. At most they define a behaviour that something is supposed to have. You still have to construct at least one object that satisfies your axioms.

But I suppose you could ask: is there an axiomatic approach to complex numbers? Sure, for example as an algebraic closure of reals. But without using reals? I've never seen it. Note that the existence of reals may be hidden somewhere. I've seen once a paper that dealt with a classification of path connected topological fields. But you can't really talk about "path connected" without reals, so yeah...

> Why is that the case?

This is a rather philosophical question. Mathematics (and any other science) doesn't really answer "why" questions but rather "how" questions.

Comment: I agree negative numbers are absurd, and who needs numbers greater than 3 anyway? The must be a product of imagination:) To be serious, thanks a lot for the input, especially the link to the axiomatic approach was really interesting. I think for me what @eyeballfrog said in the comments above was probably what made the representation of pairs of reals so much more "unnatural" compared to all the previous steps in the chain.